# How do I use grep to search for lines containing all words in a list with no specific order in a text file?

Tags: command-line, grep

How can we use `grep` to get line(s) containing a group of words, while the **order of words is not important**, although line(s) **should contain all words** mentioned in search?

I have done that with phasing the search (with piping, saving the outputs in temporary files, and searching again), but I'd like to know if I can do that in one attempt.

Here is a sample; I want to search in the lines below for lines containing **sample**, **words**, **list**:

```
it's a sample test file for a list of words.
list of words without a specific order, it's a sample.
line with no search keyword here.
list the sample files.
something completely different.
```

And get this result:

```
it's a sample test file for a list of words.
list of words without a specific order, it's a sample.
```

Comment: Are the sentences on separate lines, can OP confirm this?

Comment: This `grep -e words -e sample -e list newfile` works as well

Comment: Here are few more solutions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55391/201297

Comment: @Terrance It's AND logic OP wanted

Comment: Hi George. Yes, each sentence is on a separate line.

Comment: I edited the sample text to match the  **should contain all words** constraint

Comment: Probably `awk` better fits here.

Comment: @PerlDuck I agree, much easier.  `awk '(/sample/ && /words/ && /list/)' samplefile`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way is with multiple calls to `grep`:

```
grep sample testfile.txt | grep words | grep list
```

A demonstration:

```
echo -e "it's a sample test file for a list of words.\nlist of words without a specific order, it's a sample. \nline with no search keyword here. \nlist the sample words. \nsomething completely different." | grep sample | grep words | grep list
it's a sample test file for a list of words.
list of words without a specific order, it's a sample. 
list the sample words.
```

Comment: yes, this works as I've mentioned, but i'm looking for a one-line-solution. Although sometimes it's better to do things the easy way. thanks :)

Comment: grep -e also selects lines which have only two words (not all the words). Maybe I should try awk instead of grep, it works fine. Thank you all

Answer (score 4):

You can use lookaheads with Perl-regex (`-P`):

```
grep -P '(?=.*list)(?=.*words)(?=.*sample)'
```

---

Example:

```
echo "it's a sample test file for a list of words.
list of words without a specific order, it's a sample.
line with no search keyword here.
list the sample words.
sample line with only two of the keywords inside.
something completely different." \
| grep -P '(?=.*list)(?=.*words)(?=.*sample)'

it's a sample test file for a list of words.
list of words without a specific order, it's a sample.
list the sample words.
```

([via](https://stackoverflow.com/a/470602/7365127))

---

With `agrep` (`sudo apt install agrep`) you can chain multiple patterns:

```
agrep "sample;words;list"
```

([via](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55391/236063))